# Exactly how elliptical is Mercury's orbit, visually, without exaggeration?

Tags: orbit, mercury

Reposting question from https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5e1zhy/what_does_mercurys_orbit_really_look_like/ which reads:

> First the full question: What does the orbit of Mercury really look
>   like visually, without artistic liberties taken to amplify the
>   eccentricity of the orbit, or simplifying it to appear as a perfect
>   circle? What eccentricities are needed for orbits that readily appear
>   elliptical?

I originally did this as a self-answer, but my answer was of such poor quality I've now deleted it. I hope to do a better answer backed by some calculations, but, as always, anyone else is free to answer.

Comment: Strange wording:  the orbit just **is** , and "visually" really has nothing to do with it -- other than the angle of observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things we know about Mercury's orbit:

- **Semi-major axis:** 0.387 AU, about 57.9 million km
- **Eccentricity:** 0.205

We can calculate the semi-*minor* axis, $b$ from the equation
$$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\to b=0.379\text{ AU}$$
We can also calculate the distance to the focus from the center of the ellipse, $f$, as
$$f=ae=0.078\text{ AU}$$
I used *Mathematica*'s `ParametricPlot` to plot Mercury's orbit using these parameters, along with Earth's. Earth's semi-major axis is 1 AU, and with an eccentricity of 0.016, its semi-minor axis is about 1 to three significant figures; I've treated it as a circle. *Mathematica* gives

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{{0.387*Sin[x] - 0.0793, 0.379*Cos[x]}, {Sin[x],
  Cos[x]}}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, AxesLabel -> {AU, AU}, PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Mercury", "Earth"}], {1, 0.25}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

I'd consider the deviation from a perfect circle to be noticeable insofar as the focus is shifted from the point $(0, 0)$, but it's not incredible.

Comment: I would argue that it's not noticeable and that the primary effect of the eccentricity is that the Sun is noticeably not the center of the orbit.

Comment: @barrycarter That's basically what I meant, but I can make that clearer.

Comment: Looks OK compared with the NASA version.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Image is from [this NASA website](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2000/ast30jun_1m) and shows Earth, Mercury and Mars, with circles for comparison.

[image: Orbits of Mercury, Earth and Mars]

Answer (score 1):

@rob-jeffries and @hde-226868 have both given excellent answers: after remembering that I was the OP, I upvoted both and approved one.This answer is mostly my attempt at redemption:

[image]

The image above (Sun depicted at 3 times actual diameter) shows the 
orbit of Mercury with the Sun as the center. This agrees with two 
other images that are also meant to show Mercury's orbit to scale:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5e1zhy/what_does_mercurys_orbit_really_look_like/dab8g7q/ which links to:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HGXs0Qp.png]

- http://m.teachastronomy.com/astropedia/article/Mercurys-Orbit which embeds:

[image]

Both of these look similar to my answer, so I'm reasonably confident 
that I'm correct this 
time. https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-mercury.m 
if anyone wants to check my work

Things to note:

- The primary effect of the eccentricity is that the center of 
  Mercury's orbit is quite far from the Sun.
- The orbit's center is about 0.0796 AU or 11.9 million km from the 
  Sun, and the other focus is 23.8 million km from the Sun.
- Mercury's semiminor axis is 97.86% the length of its semimajor 
  axis, so is looks very much like a circle. To see this, we plot 
  again, this time using the midpoint of the two foci as the origin:

[image: [[image37.gif]]]

The x diameter is 587 pixels and the y diameter is 575 pixels. If you 
draw a blue circle with a radius averaging Mercury's semiminor and 
semimajor axes, you get:

[image: [[image38.gif]]]

I'll leave it to the reader to decide if Mercury's orbit does or does 
not look like a circle.